# Code only works when I use breakpoints - probably a thread issue

Tags: java, swing, input

I know this is probably a timing issue but i'm honestly not experienced enough to pin the specific thing down and figure out a fix.
Basically, it's a Connect Four game, and I'm just now learning the basics of event listeners and such.

```
package siena;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ConnectFour {
    public static int buttonPushed = -1;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = gs.getDefaultConfiguration();
        JFrame board = new JFrame("Connect Four", gc);
        board.setResizable(false);
        board.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
        board.setLayout(gridbag);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        JButton ng = new JButton("New Game");
        c.anchor = c.NORTH;
        c.fill = c.HORIZONTAL;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        board.add(ng, c);
        c.gridx = 1;
        JButton eg = new JButton("Close");
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        final JButton add[] = new JButton[7];
        ButtonClicker clickers[] = new ButtonClicker[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < clickers.length; i++) {
            clickers[i] = new ButtonClicker(i);
        }
        ng.addActionListener(clickers[0]);
        eg.addActionListener(clickers[8]);
        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            add[i] = new JButton("Drop token");
            add[i].addActionListener(clickers[i + 1]);
            c.gridx = i;
            board.add(add[i], c);
        }
        JLabel slot[][] = new JLabel[7][6];
        int slotStat[][] = new int[7][6];
        c.ipadx = 0;
        c.ipady = 0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        ImageIcon[] img = {new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new java.io.File("src/siena/gray.png"))), new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new java.io.File("src/siena/red.png"))), new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new java.io.File("src/siena/yellow.png")))};
        JLabel n = new JLabel(img[0]);
        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
                slot[x][y] = new JLabel(n.getIcon());
                slotStat[x][y] = 0;
                board.add(slot[x][y], c);
                c.gridy++;
            }
            c.gridx++;
            c.gridy = 2;
        }
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 8;
        c.gridwidth = 7;
        c.anchor = c.CENTER;
        Label info = new Label("It is the RED player's turn.");
        info.setAlignment(info.CENTER);
        board.add(info, c);
        board.pack();
        board.setVisible(true);
        boolean isRedTurn = true;
        int redCheck = 0;
        int yellowCheck = 0;
        while(buttonPushed != 9){
            while(buttonPushed == -1);
                switch(buttonPushed) {
                    case 0: 
                        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
                            for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
                                slotStat[x][y] = 0;
                                slot[x][y].setIcon(img[0]);
                                isRedTurn = true;
                            }
                        }
                        buttonPushed = -1;
                        break;
                    case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5: case 6: case 7:
                        if (slotStat[buttonPushed - 1][0] != 0) {
                            info.setText("That column is full!");
                            info.wait(100, 50000);
                            buttonPushed = -1;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
                                if (y != 5 && slotStat[buttonPushed - 1][y + 1] == 0) {
                                    //if we're not at the bottom and the slot below this one is empty
                                    if (isRedTurn) slot[buttonPushed - 1][y].setIcon(img[1]);
                                    else slot[buttonPushed - 1][y].setIcon(img[2]);
                                    Thread.sleep(200);
                                    slot[buttonPushed - 1][y].setIcon(img[0]);
                                } else {
                                    //if we're at the bottom or the slot below this one is full
                                if (isRedTurn) {
                                    slotStat[buttonPushed][y] = 1;
                                    slot[buttonPushed][y].setIcon(img[1]);
                                    redCheck++;
                                } else {
                                    slotStat[buttonPushed][y] = 2;
                                    slot[buttonPushed][y].setIcon(img[2]);
                                    yellowCheck++;
                                }
                                isRedTurn = !isRedTurn;                 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    buttonPushed = -1;
                break;
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

The ButtonPushed class is just something that extends ActionListener so i can find out what button was pressed, it has an "id" int attribute that, on button pushed gets passed to the buttonPushed int in the connect four thing

Comment: You know you're allowed to create more methods than just `main()`.

Comment: Please understand that when you post code here for review, you will often get criticism, so please don't take this the wrong way as it's meant to help you out, but having said that, yours is a terrible program as it's nothing more than one huge static main method. Use OOPs as that's what Java was built for -- use classes, instance fields and methods, constructors and the like. For your own good, delete this code and start over.

Comment: Also your while loops don't make sense in an event-driven program, and while they might work in a linear console program, that's not what you're now doing, so get rid of them. Instead deal with object state -- and this can only happen if you first make proper classes and objects.

Comment: Yeah I know, I'm primarily self-taught and I have no idea how to make good GUI stuff

Comment: Please, read and understand [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)!

Comment: Most important -- don't throw the OOP baby out with the GUI bath water. Good GUI programs start with good OOP concepts always. Also, learn basic object oriented Java concepts first before tackling complex GUI programming.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Is it okay if you elaborate on "use object state"? I'm unsure as of how to approach this kind of problem with objects and I sort of have an idea but I need an example of a good and efficient approach. I do know basic OOP stuff, it's just that, again, I'm really inexperienced with GUIs and I went with the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: The "state" usually means the state of object fields, for instance variables whose values can change when buttons are pressed. You appear to have code that waits for button *A* to be pushed, then button *B*, then... but you can't wait for things with these while loops. Instead your GUI program should have a non-GUI model or logic portion, and if button A is pressed, the model will respond depending on it's state -- is it currently expecting button A to be pressed? And if A is pressed and it stores this in a variable, then it is primed perhaps to respond to Button B's being pressed.

Comment: For instance, if it is a connect 4 game, user vs computer, the model will have a variable that tells whose turn it is. If it's the user's turn, and he presses a button for the 4th column, then the model should be informed of this, should add a *logical* user token to the 4th column, and this will then be reflected in the GUI appearance of the 4th column -- now showing a new user's disk. The model will then check for win, and if no win yet, allow the computer a turn, which then gets notified that it is its turn.

Comment: By "logic portion" do you mean something that operates in a different class/outside the GUI?

Comment: I don't think that I can say anything *specifically* right now, just that if this were my project, I'd work out my code logic first, irrespective of GUI, and then build my GUI around my logical "brains".

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can't time for me to go to bed.

Comment: You have following static variable: `public static int buttonPushed = -1;`. Further in your main method you start a while loop: `while(buttonPushed != 9){`. The first statement in your while loop is the following: `while(buttonPushed == -1);`. At that line, your program goes into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to summarize the comments, I was using the kind of structure that would be used in a linear (not event-based) program. While loops don't work when you're waiting for input, and instead of using one big static main method and a slightly modified ActionListener class, I should have used input events to call internal methods to modify internal data, then update the external GUI (in its own class and with its own class methods) based on that internal data.

If anyone needs to see an example, this is my work so far. I still need to edit some of it (namely how the program ends, and I need to add a win detector), but the GUI is fully functional.

ConnectFour class: http://pastebin.com/yeGALQn7

ButtonClicker class: http://pastebin.com/Y2y0SfW9

CFBoard class: http://pastebin.com/g9qqBmry

Oh, and, for the curious reading this, I'm reasonably sure that the reason it only works in debug mode is that the breakpoints stopped the input from conflicting with main() running through the while() loop over and over, so making it fully event-driven meant that those conflicts didn't exist anymore.

Thanks to everyone for the help, especially @HovercraftFullOfEels!

Comment: I did name a method "doThing()" in here because update() and such were already taken, which is a big faux pas. Don't be like me, kids.